# General product of multiple tensors in python

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, numeric

In python (preferrably under numpy array framework), what is the best way to do product of multiple tensors at once, instead of doing it one-by-one using numpy.tensordot? Let's suppose we need to do this summation:

```
sum over (i,j,k) of :  A[i,j] * B[j,k,l] * C[k,i]
```

where the sums are over i,j,k, and l is intentionally not summed over--thus we expect to have a 1-D vector in the end.

Answer (score 4):

Check out [`einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html).
I think `np.einsum('ij,jkl,ki', A, B, C)` will do exactly what you want.